# jQuery AJAX Passing data to controller then to view Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Here is the script

```
$.ajax({
    url: "some-function",
    type: "POST",
    data: { some-data: some-data },
    success: function(){
        window.location.replace("some-view");
    }
});
```

Here is the controller

```
public function some-function(){
    $data = $this->input->post("some-data");
    $this->load->view("some-view", array("something", $data));
}
```

Here is the view - some-view.php

```
<h1><?php echo $something ?> </h1>
```

The view does not seem to display 'some-data' that I posted from javascript.
What seems to be wrong here?

Comment: in your controller where you catch your post you need to change to `$data['some-data'] = $this->input->post('some-data', TRUE); $view = $this->load->view('some-view', $data, TRUE); print_r($view);`

Comment: You are using AJAX wrongly. What is controller/method code (and according view code) with AJAX script shown?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller where you are loading a view
Please replace

```
$this->load->view("some-view", array("something", $data));
```

To

```
$this->load->view("some-view", array("something", $data), true);
```

It will generate string output for your view.